# What does {0} mean in a string literal, for example in Console.WriteLine?

Tags: c#, variables, curly-braces, curly-brackets

I'm learning C# and came across this small piece of code:

```
{

  class Program

   {

     static void Main(string[] args)

      {

         int age = 20;// declaring variable and assign 20 to it.

         Console.WriteLine("You are {0} years old.",age);

         Console.ReadLine();

       }

   }

}
```

I dont understand how `{0}` will output 20. I mean it's not like an array index or anything so how does it know it's referring to the variable `age` ? I see the variable after the comma but would that mean that if I put {1} then it would retrieve the variable after age?

Also what is this feature called in C# I can't seem to locate it.

Comment: Why the close votes? :)

Comment: The close votes are for this question being "off topic". I personally do not think that this question is "off topic".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Also what is this feature called in C# I can't seem to locate it.

At the C# level: it isn't - because it isn't a C# feature **at all**; it is simply a library feature - see also `string.Format`. This handy utility method locates `{0}`, `{1}`, `{2}` etc and replaces them with the 0th, 1st, 2nd etc arguments. There is more to it that than, obviously (there are more complex formats available - patterns; negative vs positive, etc).

The documentation for `Console.WriteLine` is here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/828t9b9h.aspx

which links to "Composite Formatting": http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/txafckwd.aspx - which is what the BCL team call this, with intro:

> The .NET Framework composite formatting feature takes a list of objects and a composite format string as input. A composite format string consists of fixed text intermixed with indexed placeholders, called format items, that correspond to the objects in the list. The formatting operation yields a result string that consists of the original fixed text intermixed with the string representation of the objects in the list.

Answer (score 1):

It's like in standard C `printf()` function.  The values are passed after the string and are formated in order the variables are passed.

```
string.Format("Var1: {0}, var2:{1}, TheVery{3}InHere", "val1", "val2", "LongText");
```

Answer (score 0):

It is a string formatter and it will be replaced by the value.